# How to calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\left(1+{1 \over 2^{i}\ -\ i}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> How to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\left(1+{1 \over 2^{i}\ -\ i}\right)\ ?$$

I can prove this limit exists by comparing it to the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\left(1 + {1 \over 2^{i}}\right)\,,
$$
and this sequence seems to be related to q-Pochhammer, but I have no idea about the sequence in the title.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe a closed form exists?

Comment: @EricWofsey not really, I encountered this in a probability problem. I just wonder if there is some work/theory behind the limit.

Comment: @FelixMarin Please do not export your typographical colloquialisms to the questions of others. Here, using `\texttt` is uncalled for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct and easy calculation gives

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\left(1+{1 \over 2^{i}\ -\ i}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\frac{2^î}{2^î-1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2^î})}$$

The product in the denominator converges but, at least for me, it is very difficult to calculate. (*probably it could be a transcendental number*). Wolfram gives an estimate of $48$ decimal digits of which I take here only $20$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}(1-1/2^i)\approx 0.28878809508660242192.....$$

Then the approximate limit, also up to $20$ digits, is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod _{i = 1}^{n}\left(1+{1 \over 2^{i}\ -\ i}\right)\approx\color{red} {3.46274661945506360385.....}$$